# How do you run EF migrations from a custom NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget-package, entity-framework-migrations

I have a c# class libary that has its own database context and Entity Framework migrations.

My solution contains a web site that references the class library as a Project Reference.

I can apply the EF migrations for the Class Library in Visual Studio from Package Manager Console by setting the default project to my Class Library and using the following command:

```
update-database -StartupProject MyMainWebProj -Context MyClassLibDbContext
```

I have created a private NuGet package for the class libary and updated the Web Site to reference the NuGet package rather than a project reference.

I cannot figure out how to run the EF migrations now that the class library is referenced via NuGet package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the builder object of the Use*() method during service configuration like mentioned here: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/d0f133ee026aec5cd5856c5592c307b5f20fa8e4/src/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection.cs#L28

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(SomeClassInTheOtherAssembly).Assembly.FullName)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added the above to the Startup class of my Web site, (even though the context is not used in the web site - so the context is in effect just a dummy context in order to run the migrations).  Now I can run migrations from the NuGet library using the standard "update-database" command from Package Manager console.